# Viewpager inside fragment loses focus

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I have a viewpager inside a fragment, I can scroll through the pages fine. When I add a new fragment to the back stack the new fragment shows as expected in the old fragments container. Once I press back the old fragment is displayed however the view pager is no longer working, instead the focus switches to the sliding menu(the fragment layout I commit to is the central layout in feinsteins menu) and when I swipe the sliding menu opens up instead of moving to the next page in the viewpager. Why might this be?

Here is my Viewpager adapter which is subclassed inside the fragment atm

```
    static class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private static int[] sDrawables = { R.drawable.main1, R.drawable.main3,
                    R.drawable.main2, R.drawable.main3, R.drawable.main4,
                    R.drawable.main5 };

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return sDrawables.length;
            }

            @Override
            public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(container.getContext());
                imageView.setImageResource(sDrawables[position]);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//thiscalls back to the Fragmentctivity and switches to the new fragment, problems arise when I go back to this fragment and the viewpager wont swipe to next page
                        ((LeftAndRightActivity) cx).switchFragmentTo(12);

                    }
                });

                // Now just add ImageView to ViewPager and return it
                container.addView(imageView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                return imageView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }
        }
```

Here is onCreateView() of my fragment which contains the viewpager( I am actually using the PullToRefresh Viewpager by ChrisBanes)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null)
            return null;

        if (v != null)
            return v;

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.savescreenlayout, container, false);

        mPullToRefreshViewPager = (PullToRefreshBase) v
                .findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_viewpager);
        mPullToRefreshViewPager.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mPullToRefreshViewPager.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_END);

        vp = (ViewPager) mPullToRefreshViewPager.getRefreshableView();

        vp.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

        return v;
    }
```

The first time my Fragment with the viewpager is commited its fine, its just when I come back from any other fragment that the viewpager stops paging and the sliding menu opens up instead. thanks for any help in advance

Comment: can you show us your view pager codes?

Comment: thanks, I added the pageradapter code and my fragment onCreateView()